# What is $TEXMFCNF for?

Tags: installing, file-lookup

I just got told, in the comments to my answer to the question [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/1110#1110), that I shouldn't set the environment variable `$TEXMFCNF` if I install TeXLive myself (rather than letting my distribution do it for me).

I checked, and on one machine where I've installed TL2010 on top of an existing Ubuntu distribution then I hadn't set `$TEXMFCNF` and everything had been working just fine.  On another machine, I had set `$TEXMFCNF` (and everything had been working just fine as well).  The difference between the two machines is that on the first I have admin rights and so installed TL2010 in to `/usr/local/` whereas on the other I don't and so installed TL2010 in to `$HOME/local/`.  When I set and unset `$TEXMFCNF` on the second machine then I get different answers for `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`, *but* the two answers are in the same basic place.  So it seems that `kpsewhich` can figure out where `texmf.cnf` is based on ... what?  I'm not sure what information `kpathsea` has to deduce the location of `texmf.cnf`.

With $TEXMFCNF set to `$HOME/local/texlive/2010/texmf/web2c/` then `kpsewhich texmf.cnf` reports `$HOME/local/texlive/2010/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf`.  With it unset, then `kpsewhich` reports `/somewhere/else/texlive/2010/texmf.cnf`, **but** `$HOME/local` is a symlink to `/somewhere/else` so these are in the same installation of TL2010.  `kpsewhich` itself is in `$HOME/local/bin` but the file there is actually a symlink to somewhere in the TL texmf-tree.

Lastly, I have no idea why I started setting `$TEXMFCNF`.  The reason why is lost in the mists of time.  I suspect that it is because once long ago I was happy with the TeX installation provided for me except that I didn't like the value of the home texmf tree, so I had my own `texmf.cnf` which overrode this.

So, to the question(s):

1. (the main one): Is setting `$TEXMFCNF` good, bad, or ugly?
2. (the what's-going-on one): How does `kpathsea` even start knowing where to look?  As in, it has to find a configuration file somewhere telling it where to find all the other stuff, so how does it deduce where to find it?

(To focus thoughts on that last one, I can well believe that `kpsewhich` can deduce something from its location; so if I *copied* `kpsewhich` in to `$HOME/local/bin` rather than symlinked then would that break everything?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A partial answer: The file `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf` (on my system) contains the lines

```
% This definition isn't used from this .cnf file itself (that would be
% paradoxical), but the compile-time default in paths.h is built from it.
% The SELFAUTO* variables are set automatically from the location of
% argv[0], in kpse_set_program_name.
% 
% This main texmf.cnf file is installed, for a release YYYY, in a
% directory such as /usr/local/texlive/YYYY/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf.
% Since this file is subject to future updates, the TeX Live installer
% or human administrator may also create a file
% /usr/local/texlive/YYYY/texmf.cnf; any settings in this latter file
% will take precedence over the distributed one under texmf/web2c.
% 
% For security reasons, it is better not to include . in this path.
%
TEXMFCNF = {$SELFAUTOLOC,$SELFAUTODIR,$SELFAUTOPARENT}{,{/share/texmf{-local,}/web2c}
```

That first paragraph confirms that, yes, `kpsewhich` uses its own location to find everything.  (I also tested your suggestion of copying `kpsewhich` to a new place and seeing that it couldn't find anything.)

**Edit:** Further info: I tried setting $TEXMFCNF (it hadn't been set on my system).  With $TEXMFCNF set to a list of directories, kpsewhich would look *only* in those directories for texmf.cnf.  You can see this by setting $TEXMFCNF to a list of directories none of which contain texmf.cnf; if you then run `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`, it complains that it couldn't find texmf.cnf in any of those directories.  Thus, if you set $TEXMFCNF, you need to be sure it includes all of the directories that contain a texmf.cnf that you want kpsewhich to search.